# How do you fix this notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 with stripslashes?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I upload my theme to WordPress, I get this notice in the options page:

> Uninitialized string offset: 0

This is my code:

```
function name_of_function ( $args ) {
    extract( $args );
    $option_name = 'the_theme_options';
    $options = get_option( $option_name );
    switch ( $type ) {  
        case 'text':
            $options[$id] = stripslashes( $options[$id] );
            $options[$id] = esc_attr( $options[$id] );
            echo "<input class='regular-text$class' type='text' id='$id' name='" . $option_name . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
            echo ( $desc != '' ) ? "<br><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";
        break;
```

When I save, the notice goes away.

I tried adding isset, like this (I was getting Notice:undefined index at first):

```
$options[$id] = stripslashes( isset( $options[$id] );
```

The errors go away but it fails to save.

Then I added isset to the following line:

```
$options[$id] = esc_attr( isset( $options[$id] ) );
```

Still didn't work.

I tried removing this line but I still get errors:

```
$options[$id] = stripslashes( $options[$id] );
```

I even tried this:

```
if ( isset( $options[$id] ) {
    $options[$id] = stripslashes( $options[$id] );
}
```

I'm aware now that some of the things I tried don't make sense.

I've been searching for hours. Read some docs. Can't seem to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$options` is a [**string in this context**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option), not an array. You are trying to treat it like an array, which doesn't work.  The logic in your code will never work; it's not clear what you're trying to do with `$options[$id]`.

The reason you get

> Uninitialized string offset: 0

is that `$id` is not initialized anywhere, so PHP treats it as `0`. You are saying, "look at this string ($options) and get the array value at key 0," and PHP throws its hands up because that doesn't make sense.

Your various solutions won't work for several other reasons.  `stripslashes( isset( $options[$id] );` fails because (1) `$options[$id]` doesn't exist and (2) `stripslashes()` takes a string parameter, but you are handing it a boolean value.  Same problem with `esc_attr( isset( $options[$id] ) );`

Comment: Well this explains why my checkbox was working when the rest wasn't. Thank you! How would I define $id?

Comment: I'm glad it helps! Please accept the answer if you found it helpful. :)  As for defining `$id`: it's not clear what you expect `$id` to be or what you are trying to do with it. You have several uninitialized variables in the code above (`$id`, `$type`, and `$desc`), so it is hard to tell what you are trying to do. The best way to get help is to revise your code and then post a new question containing the new code if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just posted the question. If you could take a look at it and help, that would be appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489669/how-to-initialize-id-from-another-function