# Display array in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert and display array of elements in php mysql. Inserting data into table works fine. While displaying the multiple fields gives error `Uninitialized string offset: 0`. What may be reason of displaying array in php mysql?

Here is the code

```
//Inserting the data
for($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['slno1']);$i++)
    {
    $slno1 = $_REQUEST["slno1"][$i];
    $name1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["name1"][$i]));
    $rhof1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["rhof1"][$i]));
    $dob1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["dob1"][$i]));
    $dobapt1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["dobapt1"][$i]));
    $doc1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["doc1"][$i]));
    $doconf1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["doconf1"][$i]));
    $qualification1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["qualification1"][$i]));
    $school1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["school1"][$i]));
    $occupation1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST["occupation1"][$i]));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (memid,slno1,name1,rhof1,dob1,dobapt1,doc1,doconf1,qualification1,school1,occupation1)VALUES('$id','$slno1','$name1','$rhof1','$dob1','$dobapt1','$doc1','$doconf1','$qualification1','$school1','$occupation1')") or die(mysql_error()); 

    }

//Displaying the data in php mysql
$run=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where memid='$id'");
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
$slno=$row['slno1'];
$name=$row['name1'];
$rhof=$row['rhof1'];
$dob=$row['dob1'];
$dobapt=$row['dobapt1'];
$doc=$row['doc1'];
$doconf=$row['doconf1'];
$school=$row['school1'];
$qualification=$row['qualification1'];
$occupation=$row['occupation1'];
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488524/how-do-you-fix-this-notice-uninitialized-string-offset-0-with-stripslashes

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, try pdo or mysqli.

Comment: You need to upgrade Your Php asap. go for php 7 and use latest libraries like `mysqli_*` and `PDO` along with `prepared statements` (To prevent from `SQL INJECTION`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))
```

try

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
```